# Identify the structure of a .dat file in python

Tags: python, encoding, binary, mt4

I have a .dat file that is coming from Mt4 platform and I want to read its content outside of mt4 but I cannot identify the encoding.

I tried to use the `struct` library in python but I have to define its structure first in order to read it, but I don't know the encoding. I also tried to convert it to different encodings using text editors, but again I did not get the desired outcome.

Comment: `.dat` is a generic suffix that's used by many applications for their binary data files, there's no standard encoding. You need to find documentation specific to the application that created it, otherwise this will be a complex reverse engineering task.

Comment: It may be a proprietary format, so they might not make the details of decoding it public.